# condition to not add amounts and dates in column

Tags: python, pandas

```
   TTT
1. 802010001-999-00000285-888-
2. 256788
3. 1940
4. NaN
5. 10/1/2020  12:00:00 AM  
6. 702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-
```

I want to Fill column GGT column with all other values except for the amounts and dates

Required table would be like this

```
   TTT                                GGT
1. 802010001-999-00000285-888-        802010001-999-00000285-888-
2. 256788                             NaN
3. 1940                               NaN
4. NaN                                NaN
5. 10/1/2020  12:00:00 AM             NaN
6. 702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-      702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-
```

the orginal table has more than 200thousands rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for misisng values if no match, chain by `|` for bitwise `OR` and pass to [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
m = (pd.to_datetime(df['TTT'], errors='coerce').notna() | 
     pd.to_numeric(df['TTT'], errors='coerce').notna())
df['GGT'] = df['TTT'].mask(m)
print (df)
                             TTT                            GGT
0    802010001-999-00000285-888-    802010001-999-00000285-888-
1                         256788                            NaN
2                           1940                            NaN
3                            NaN                            NaN
4         10/1/2020  12:00:00 AM                            NaN
5  702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-  702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-
```